# French characters in SQLite..how to display properly in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, sqlite, special-characters

I am working on an iPhone app using a SQLite db. I have some French characters that are not rendering properly in the app - they are being displayed as squares.

The character set client is: utf8. Is there an easy fix for this?

Comment: Could you post some code snippets showing how you store and retrieve the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the font I was using did not render those characters correctly! Problem solved!

Check your fonts!

Answer (score 2):

Check that everything is using UEF8, including the database, table and row. Try using some of the sample code with French characters.

You can use [SQLiteManager](http://www.sqlabs.net/sqlitemanager.php) to see how your database was created and whether it's using UTF8.